# Make variables defined in python readable by other languages

Tags: c++, python-2.7

I have a python module that defines some paths when imported. I want those paths to be readable by scripts in c++ and shell.

One option would be to make a text file with those paths, and write a reader in python, c++ and shell, and then start all my scripts with the respective reader, but it's a solution I dislike. I would be constantly opening the text file, and it could give me issues if more than one script tries opening it at the same time.

Another solution would be to have the python file define the paths as environment variables instead. The usual way to do environment variables in python, os.environ, only lasts until I close python. Could anyone tell me how to do this?

(Defining these variables in my .bashrc would be quite the headache, because the module will also be used by other people, and the paths have to be changed from time to time.)

Any other way to solve this problem would also be appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered [boost.python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/python/doc/index.html) for C++?

Comment: What "issues" do you anticipate from multiple scripts opening the same file for reading?  And would any of them need to open it more than once?

Comment: @Borgleader: I am trying to avoid solutions for specific languages, because I do not know when I will need to add a new one because of this or that homebrew module made by a coworker.

Comment: @ScottHunter: no script would need to open the file for reading more than once. However, occasionally a lot of them have to be launched at the same time, and it can be quite a mess to find out which one didn't end correctly. I am not entirely sure if trying to read an already opened file is a possible source of errors here, but I might as well avoid it if possible.